# How do I split all merged cells for a specific sheet within a Google Spreadsheet using Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm working with Google sheet API and I have defined the following functions:

```
def service():
    secret_id_gsuite_token = 'my_token' # AWS Secret with token
    gsheet = GSheets(secret_id_gsuite_token)
    return gsheet
```

To update a sheet with information present in a pandas dataframe:

```
def df_to_googlesheet(gsheet, df, gsheetId, sheet_name):   
    output = gsheet.spreadsheets.values().update(
    spreadsheetId = gsheetId,
    valueInputOption = 'RAW',
    range = sheet_name + '!A1',
    body = dict(
        majorDimension = 'ROWS',
        values = df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist())
    ).execute()
```

To make a request to merge cells to form a "block":

```
def merge_cells_request(sheeId, start_row, end_row, start_col, end_col):
    request = [{"mergeCells": { "range": { "sheetId": sheeId,
                                           "startRowIndex": start_row,
                                           "endRowIndex": end_row,
                                           "startColumnIndex": start_col,
                                           "endColumnIndex": end_col},
                                "mergeType": "MERGE_ALL"}}]
    return request
```

I also have a similar function to make requests to color cells backgrounds. I put all my request in a **requests** list and apply them running:

```
gsheet.batch_update(gsheetId, requests)
```

This batch_update function uses the **batchUpdate()** method of google sheets api.

Finally this is the function to clear the sheet:

```
def clear_sheet(gsheet, spreadsheetId, sheeId):
    clear_request = [{"updateCells": {"range": {"sheetId": sheeId},
                                      "fields": "*"}}]

    gsheet.batch_update(spreadsheetId, clear_request)
```

The problem is that this last function does not clear the merged cells, I want to unmerge all merged cells in order to have the sheet totally clean again, but none of the options I found online seems to fit my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- From `I want to unmerge all merged cells in order to have the sheet totally clean again`, you want to unmerge cells in a sheet using Sheets API.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, I would like to propose to use UnmergeCellsRequest of the batchUpdate method in Sheets API.

The request body is as follows.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "unmergeCells": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheeId
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- Although I'm not sure about your whole script, from your following script

  ```
    def clear_sheet(gsheet, spreadsheetId, sheeId):
        clear_request = [{"updateCells": {"range": {"sheetId": sheeId},
                                          "fields": "*"}}]

        gsheet.batch_update(spreadsheetId, clear_request)
  ```

  - In this case, the request of `gsheet.batch_update()` might be as follows.

    ```
      [{"unmergeCells": {"range": {"sheetId": sheeId}}}]
    ```

#### Reference:

- [UnmergeCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#unmergecellsrequest)

Comment: I had to make this request actually:  [{"unmergeCells": {"range": {"sheetId": sheeId,
                                                   "startRowIndex": 0,
                                                   "endRowIndex": 100,
                                                   "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                                   "endColumnIndex": 100}}}]  but it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Lucy_in_the_sky_with_diamonds Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.